# How to leave a section before the end without a goto statement

Tags: cobol

In cobol a section (similar to a function in c) can look like this:

```
abc section.
  command a
  command b
  if a = 4
    go to abc-end
  end-if
  command c
  command d.       
abc-end.
  exit.
```

Until now, the only possibility for me to leave the section before the end (on a = 4), was with the command "goto".

Is there any other way to do it without goto?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I was hoping that this was an interview question. Which compiler and OS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the draft, FCD 1.0(E) 2010-08-06

```
The EXIT PARAGRAPH and EXIT SECTION statements provide a means of exiting a
structured procedure without executing any of the following statements within
the procedure.
```

Comment: Yes, but these are thinly disguised GO TOs. `EXIT SECTION` is relatively safe (no worse than the GO TO) but `EXIT PARAGRAPH` is going to be fun if people expect it to terminate a `PERFORM ... THRU ...` with more than the second paragraph just being an a label for the no-code-generated `EXIT`.

Answer (score 2):

Like this for your example.

```
abc section.
  command a
  command b
  if a NOT EQUAL TO 4
      command c
      command d
  end-if
  .
```

Like this for something invented but with names to help grasp the thing.

```
30D-UNPACK-CRATE SECTION.
    PERFORM                     30DA-COMMON-PER-CRATE
    IF NOT STANDARD-CRATE
        PERFORM                 30DD-NON-STANDARD-CRATE
    END-IF
    .
```

or

```
30D-UNPACK-CRATE SECTION.
    PERFORM                     30DA-COMMON-PER-CRATE
    IF SPECIAL-CRATE
        PERFORM                 30DD-NON-STANDARD-CRATE
    END-IF
    .
```

This uses 88-level Condition Names, so might be

```
88  STANDARD-CRATE                      VALUE "A" THRU "D" "J" "2".
88  SPECIAL-CRATE                       VALUE "X" "Z".
```

Again, just examples.

Apart from the fact that you are already using SECTIONs (and if you have a SECTION all the paragraphs before the next section belong to that, so you can't have isolated paragraphs) the above could either be a SECTION or a paragraph. No need for PERFORM .... THRU ... or the ... SECTION. Except for local standards... and, with SECTIONs, how the program is already coded.

EXIT PARAGRAPH and EXIT SECTION.

These may or may not be available on thee compiler that you are using.

Be aware that they are functionally equivalent to a GO TO, with some caveats, so replacing GO TOs by them will give a false sense of... I don't know what, but it'll be false.

```
PERFORM THE-FIRST


THE-FIRST SECTION.
TF-1.
    some code
    .
TF-2.
    some code
    .
TF-9.
    some code
    .
```

Different program:

```
PERFORM A-PARAGRAPH THRU AP-9


A-PARAGRAPH.
    some code
    .
AP-1.
    some code
    .
AP-9.
    some code
    .
```

Often you will find the final paragraph of a SECTION just contains `EXIT` (and be aware that `EXIT` generates no code, it is just a placeholder) and a similar situation with `PERFORM ... THRU ...`.

Usually `PERFORM ... THRU ...` will only contain two paragraphs, but there is nothing except local standards which says it is so.

`EXIT SECTION` will "GO TO" an assumed CONTINUE statement immediately prior to the full-stop/period which terminates the SECTION.

`EXIT PARAGRAPH` will "GO TO" an assumed CONTINUE statement immediately prior to the full-stop/period which terminates the paragraph

If `EXIT PARAGRAPH` is used within a SECTION, or within the range of a `PERFORM ... THRU ...` which contains more than one paragraph excluding any that solely uses `EXIT`, it will probably not work as the author expects nor as the next reader expects.

```
THE-FIRST SECTION.
TF-1.
    some code
    IF condition
        EXIT PARAGRAPH
    END-IF
    some more code
    IF condition
        EXIT SECTION
    END-IF
    some more code
    <EXIT PARAGRAPH will arrive here>
    .
TF-2.
    some code
    .
TF-9.
    some code
    <EXIT SECTION will arrive here>
    .

A-PARAGRAPH.
    some code
    IF condition
        EXIT PARAGRAPH (a - just descriptive, not syntax)
    END-IF
    some more code
    <EXIT PARAGRAPH (a) will arrive here>
    .
AP-1.
    some code
    IF condition
        EXIT PARAGRAPH (b - just descriptive, not syntax)
    END-IF
    some more code
    <EXIT PARAGRAPH (b) will arrive here>
    .
AP-9.
    some code
    .
```

So, if using `EXIT PARAGRAPH` in a SECTION or in a `PERFORM ... THRU ...` with more than one paragraph containing other than a single `EXIT`, then you're creating a potentially worse situation than using a plain GO TO (where it is blindingly obvious what the intended destination of the branch is) whilst using a construct which looks to be "structured".

Comment: This would be a great answer if weren't so big - try shorten it or move the answering example to the top